# ServiceStack ApiKeyAuthProvider fires 6 select statements on every request

Tags: c#, .net, caching, servicestack

I have a web service that's configured to use the `ApiKeyAuthProvider` like so:

```
container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
container.Register<IAuthRepository>(c => new OrmLiteAuthRepository(c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>(), "UserDb"));
container.Resolve<IAuthRepository>().InitSchema();
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
    new IAuthProvider[]
    {
        new ApiKeyAuthProvider(AppSettings) { ServiceRoutes = new Dictionary<Type, string[]>() }
    }));
```

I also have OrmLite dumping the SQL to a log file.

```
SQL: SELECT "Id", "UserAuthId", "Environment", "KeyType", "CreatedDate", "ExpiryDate", "CancelledDate", "Notes", "RefId", "RefIdStr", "Meta" FROM "ApiKey" WHERE "Id" = @Id
PARAMS: Id=APITOKENHERE 

SQL: SELECT "Id", "UserName", "Email", "PrimaryEmail", "PhoneNumber", "FirstName", "LastName", "DisplayName", "Company", "BirthDate", "BirthDateRaw", "Address", "Address2", "City", "State", "Country", "Culture", "FullName", "Gender", "Language", "MailAddress", "Nickname", "PostalCode", "TimeZone", "Salt", "PasswordHash", "DigestHa1Hash", "Roles", "Permissions", "CreatedDate", "ModifiedDate", "InvalidLoginAttempts", "LastLoginAttempt", "LockedDate", "RecoveryToken", "RefId", "RefIdStr", "Meta" FROM "UserAuth" WHERE "Id" = @Id
PARAMS: Id=1  

SQL: SELECT "Id", "UserAuthId", "Provider", "UserId", "UserName", "FullName", "DisplayName", "FirstName", "LastName", "Company", "Email", "PhoneNumber", "BirthDate", "BirthDateRaw", "Address", "Address2", "City", "State", "Country", "Culture", "Gender", "Language", "MailAddress", "Nickname", "PostalCode", "TimeZone", "RefreshToken", "RefreshTokenExpiry", "RequestToken", "RequestTokenSecret", "Items", "AccessToken", "AccessTokenSecret", "CreatedDate", "ModifiedDate", "RefId", "RefIdStr", "Meta" 
FROM "UserAuthDetails"
WHERE ("UserAuthId" = @0)
PARAMS: @0=1  

SQL: SELECT "Id", "UserName", "Email", "PrimaryEmail", "PhoneNumber", "FirstName", "LastName", "DisplayName", "Company", "BirthDate", "BirthDateRaw", "Address", "Address2", "City", "State", "Country", "Culture", "FullName", "Gender", "Language", "MailAddress", "Nickname", "PostalCode", "TimeZone", "Salt", "PasswordHash", "DigestHa1Hash", "Roles", "Permissions", "CreatedDate", "ModifiedDate", "InvalidLoginAttempts", "LastLoginAttempt", "LockedDate", "RecoveryToken", "RefId", "RefIdStr", "Meta" FROM "UserAuth" WHERE "Id" = @Id
PARAMS: Id=1  

SQL: SELECT "Id", "UserName", "Email", "PrimaryEmail", "PhoneNumber", "FirstName", "LastName", "DisplayName", "Company", "BirthDate", "BirthDateRaw", "Address", "Address2", "City", "State", "Country", "Culture", "FullName", "Gender", "Language", "MailAddress", "Nickname", "PostalCode", "TimeZone", "Salt", "PasswordHash", "DigestHa1Hash", "Roles", "Permissions", "CreatedDate", "ModifiedDate", "InvalidLoginAttempts", "LastLoginAttempt", "LockedDate", "RecoveryToken", "RefId", "RefIdStr", "Meta" FROM "UserAuth" WHERE "Id" = @Id
PARAMS: Id=1  

SQL: SELECT "Id", "UserAuthId", "Provider", "UserId", "UserName", "FullName", "DisplayName", "FirstName", "LastName", "Company", "Email", "PhoneNumber", "BirthDate", "BirthDateRaw", "Address", "Address2", "City", "State", "Country", "Culture", "Gender", "Language", "MailAddress", "Nickname", "PostalCode", "TimeZone", "RefreshToken", "RefreshTokenExpiry", "RequestToken", "RequestTokenSecret", "Items", "AccessToken", "AccessTokenSecret", "CreatedDate", "ModifiedDate", "RefId", "RefIdStr", "Meta" 
FROM "UserAuthDetails"
WHERE ("UserAuthId" = @0)
PARAMS: @0=1
```

I expected the [sessions to be cached](http://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#user-sessions-cache) and not hit the database for every request. That doesn't seem to be what it's doing, however. For every request I send to my API, it's firing those same 6 select statements to the auth database. I don't know if I'm just expecting it to do something that it's not designed to do or if I'm missing a piece somewhere.

In the grand scheme of things they don't take long to run, but no matter what else the service does it will always take at least 200 ms to run those selects.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [API Key Auth Provider](http://docs.servicestack.net/api-key-authprovider) is a stateless AuthProvider which doesn't cache any Authenticated User Sessions in between requests by default and therefore needs re-authenticate on every request.

#### [Cached API Key Sessions](http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v4.5.6#cached-api-key-sessions)

But in ServiceStack's latest v4.5.6 release you can reduce the number of I/O Requests and improve the performance of API Key Auth Provider Requests by specifying a SessionCacheDuration to temporarily store the Authenticated UserSession against the API Key which will reduce subsequent API Key requests down to 1 DB call to fetch and validate the API Key + 1 Cache Hit to restore the User’s Session which if you’re using the default in-memory Cache will mean it only requires 1 I/O call for the DB request.

This can be enabled with:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(...,
    new IAuthProvider[] {
        new ApiKeyAuthProvider(AppSettings) {
            SessionCacheDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
        }
    }));
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks for your help @mythz. What a coincidence that no sooner did I ask the question and you released the latest version with the feature.